# How to make a view helper using a block

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Rails 7, I have the following view helper

```rb
def my_list
  tag.ul(class: "...", data: {controller: "my_controller"}) do
    "<li>...</li>".html_safe
  end
end
```

which renders fine.
Now, I want to extract the list items and make the helper work with a block

```rb
<%= my_list do %>
  <li>...</li>
<% end %>
```

So, I tried to use `capture` as follows:

```rb
def my_list(&block)
  tag.ul(class: "...", data: {controller: "my_controller"}) do
    capture(&block)
  end
end
```

But, it renders nothing.

What am I missing here?

The syntax looks fine to me. Here is a similar snippet that runs without problems.

[image]

Comment: Your code looks OK except `data: {...}`

Comment: What's wrong with that?

Comment: Perhaps, you see something that I'm missing.

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers or translation tools. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or easily copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: You can always pass the block through, as in `tag.ul(..., &block)`.

Comment: `...` is [forward operator](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/16253). `def my_list(&block); tag.ul(class: "...") do; capture(&block); end; end;` works well and render HTML as expected, I can't reproduce your behaviour. Probably there is some extra feature in your original code